# How to provide "post to my timeline" feature in HTML-based Facebook canvas app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-timeline

I am having an HTML-based Facebook application, running on Facebook canvas.
It is not part of Facebook AppCenter yet.

I am looking for an easy way for the application users to post information about my application - if they would like to - to their timeline. I am not asking for a permission to post on user's timeline (may not be appropriate) - I want instead to make it easy to do that "manually".

When looking at the applications in AppCenter, there is a "Share" link
Like here: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/texas_holdem?fb_source=appcenter_search
on the right side...

Clicking on the link leads to what I want to achieve - picture is here - 
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1xQjdje-0viXdF0mL4Ay3rqayAJ5zQmqPNWW0eqFDq3k/pub?w=960&h=720
 but inside my own HTML-based app.

I reviewed the Social Plugins documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/
, and managed to create a control that helps sending information on my app - but only to specific users!

Yet I failed to find how to implement the "post to my timeline" feature.

Is it something limited to AppCenter applications, or maybe I am missing something simple? What's the closest way to get to what I would like to achieve?

Thanks for any hint.

Max.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Any idea why Feed Dialog is separated from the Social Plugins?

Comment: Also, I saw some sites using sharer.php, like: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fslotomania - same thing?

Comment: The Sharer is the old way of doing this – it still works, but it is not documented any more and there is no guarantee for how long it will continue to work.